# Export-CSV - (Powershell)

Tags: windows, csv, powershell, automation

So i have the bottom scriptblock:

```
Import-csv C:\file_location.csv | foreach-object {
Get-WmiObject -computername $_.computername -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username} | `
Select-Object computername, username | Export-CSV C:\file_location.csv -notypeinformation
```

the exported csv shows the Computer Name header but no actual computer and the username header is just fine.  What and where am I missing something from?

Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Export-CSV issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233416/powershell-export-csv-issues)

Answer (score 0):

<s>`select` (which is an alias for `Select-Object`) returns an object with *only* the properties you specify. So when you did your first `select username` you got an object with just the username; all other properties were discarded, so when the second `Select-Object` call runs, there is no `computername` for it to return.</s>

The first `select` seems completely unnecessary there; just take it out and I think everything will work as expected.

EDIT: I see now that `computername` is not a property of the returned WMI object; it came from the CSV. Your `ForEach-Object` is only returning the WMI object, so the CSV row object is being discarded.

What you need to do is add the `computername` from the CSV to the WMI object, which you can do with `Select-Object` (with a computed column) or `Add-Member`:

```
Import-csv C:\file_location.csv | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -computername $_.computername -class Win32_ComputerSystem |
        Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_.computername}},username
    } | 
    Export-CSV C:\file_location.csv -notypeinformation
```

Or:

```
Import-csv C:\file_location.csv | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -computername $_.computername -class Win32_ComputerSystem |
        Add-Member -NotePropertyName computername -NotePropertyValue $_.computername -Force -PassThru
    } | 
    Select-Object computername, username
    Export-CSV C:\file_location.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried both methods and still the same.  The select object method delivers the same results, ComputerName header with no data in the column.  The Add-Member exports a blank CSV.

Comment: Scratch that!! I found my mistake.  The Add-Member worked perfectly.  Thank you @briantist!!