# Powershell Export-CSV issues

Tags: powershell, csv, properties, export, output

I currently have the following script that works well for gathering a list of installed programs from a list of remote computers.

```
$PCListOld = Get-Content F:\PCList-Old.txt
ForEach ($PC in $PCListOld)
    {
    $AppList = Get-WmiObject -Computer $PC Win32_Product | Sort-Object Name
    $AppList | Export-CSV C:\~Scripts\AppLists\$PC.csv
    }
```

However, I really only need the Name property in $AppList, but if I simply pipe $AppList.Name to Export-CSV, I don't get the same output in the csv as I would have on the screen.  Can someone give me some advice on how I should edit this so I can just get the Name value exported to the csv file?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the result properties to just `Name` via `Select-Object`:

```
foreach ($PC in $PCListOld) {
    Get-WmiObject -Computer $PC Win32_Product |
        Sort-Object Name |
        Select-Object Name |
        Export-Csv C:\~Scripts\AppLists\$PC.csv
}
```